# Getting the desired string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]
a = "8hypotheticall024y6wxz"
alp = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZ"
alph = alp.lower()
b= split(alph)
c = set(b)-set(a)
c = sorted(c)
c = str(c)


res = [int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()]
num_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
l = set(num_list)-set(res)
l = sorted(l)
l = str(l)
print(l,c)
```

The output I get is

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'q', 'r', 's', 'v']
```

The output I want is

```
"13579bdfgjkmnqrsuv"
```

How do I get it?
Please provide me with the code to get rid of these square brackets, commas and quotation marks.

Comment: Instead of `str(c)` use `''.join()` to create a string. Same for `l`

Comment: How is `u`  the 2nd last letter

Comment: @PCM, I think OP forgot to add `U` in `alp`. Same for `J`

Comment: @kuro lol, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

Add this is in the last -

```
l.extend(c)
l = [str(i) for i in l]

print(''.join(l)) # 13579bdfgkmnqrsv
```

Additionally, you could simplify your code (No need of function and many reassignments) -

```
a = "8hypotheticall024y6wxz"
alp = "ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZ"
b = alp.lower()
c = sorted(set(b)-set(a))


res = [int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()]
num_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
l = sorted(set(num_list)-set(res))

l.extend(c)
l = [str(i) for i in l]

print(''.join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make another string like this

```
str = ""
for i in [your output list]:
    str += i
```

Comment: Or use list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

For the list c, which is a list of strings, you can convert it with `''.join(c)` instead of `str(c)`.

For the list l, you can do the same thing but you have to convert every element to a string. One concise way to do this is with, `map(str, l)`. To accomplish the conversion in one line, you could to `''.join(map(str,l))`